# how can send inlineKeyboard with answerInlineQuery Telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot with [irazasyed](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) package and set it to 'inline mode' now when user type (@botid aboutus) bot show text for user like below :
[image]

now i need when user click to that item, bot send inlineKeyboard to user like below :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
$results= json_encode(  [ 
    [
    'type' => "article",
    'id'=> "1", 


    'title'=> "chek inline keybord ",
    'description'=> "test ",
    'caption'=> "caption" ,
    'input_message_content'=> ['message_text' => "you can share inline keyboard to other chat"],
    'reply_markup'=>['inline_keyboard'=>[
                        [
                            ['text'=>"text1",'url'=>''],
                            ['text'=>"text2",'url'=>''],
                            ['text'=>"shareToOtherChat",'switch_inline_query'=>'chek']
                        ]
                        ]],
    'thumb_url'=> "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/10547598?v=3&s=88",
    ]
    ] );
```